# How to add radio buttons in different numbers and add edit text in list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add radio buttons to quiz app. each questions may have different number of options. for example some questions have 2 options and some have 3 options how to add that in list view. as well as some questions don't have any options in that time i have to add text field. how to do that in list view.

Here 1st question has 2 radio buttons and 2nd question has 3 radio buttons and 3rd question has text field

[image]

```
List<Widget> makeRadios(List options) {// creating radio buttons based on options
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();

    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      list.add(new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text('Radio $i'),
          new Radio(
              value: i,
              groupValue: _selected,
              onChanged: (int value) {
                onChanged(value);
              })
        ],
      ));
    }

    return list;
  }

  Widget create_qstns(String qsn, List options) {// add radio widget to each questions
    return new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          new Text(
            qsn,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
          Column(children: makeRadios(options)),
        ]);
  }
```

Here is data json

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you feel being pulled to one side while walking?",
    "Options": "Double vision,Slurring of speech or mispronunciation,Numbness of face,None",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you experience any of these before, during or after the giddiness episodes?",
    "Options": "Ringing sounds in the ear,Fullness in the ear,Reduced hearing,None",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 2.1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Which ear?",
    "Options": "Right ear,Left ear",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 2.2,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "How long do your giddy episodes last?",
    "Options": "Seconds,About one to two minutes,More than five minutes but less than half hour,Few hours,More than 24 hours",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 2.3,
    "Type": "Input",
    "Question": "When was the first time you had your giddiness episode?(fill in how long ago or approximate month and year)",
    "Options": null,
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Can you reproduce the symptoms on your own?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 3.1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Which of these things can bring about giddiness",
    "Options": "Turning in bed,Looking down,Looking up",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Did you ever have a fall?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 4.1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Was the fall because of your giddiness",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you feel swaying sensation while walking?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you feel being pulled to one side while walking?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you get headaches?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 7.1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you get any of the following during headache?",
    "Options": "Nausea,Vomiting,Intolerance to light,Intolerance to sound,Intolerance to smell",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 8,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Have you identified any triggers for your giddiness episodes?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 8.1,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Which of the following triggers your giddiness?",
    "Options": "Missed sleep,Travel,Stress,Hunger,Smells,None of the above",
    "IsNested": true,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 9,
    "Type": "Input",
    "Question": "How frequently do you get the giddiness episodes?",
    "Options": null,
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 10,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "How do you describe the course of the condition you are facing?",
    "Options": "Getting worser day by day,Getting better day by day,It has been the same,None of the above",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 11,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you have motion sickness?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 12,
    "Type": "Multiple",
    "Question": "Do you feel uneasy looking at fast moving objects?",
    "Options": "Yes,No",
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 13,
    "Type": "Input",
    "Question": "Which medicine made you better (at least temporarily)?",
    "Options": null,
    "IsNested": false,
    "Result": null
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, please check i have added snippets.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing, and can I see the data, how does it look? `makeRadios` is working fine?

Comment: some of questions may have 2 options,some have 3 options how to do that. i'm using json data

Comment: Hey @PrithamBnr did you try the solution provided for your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your code, this is the place where you are building your question,

```
Widget create_qstns(String qsn, List options) {// add radio widget to each questions
    return new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          new Text(
            qsn,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
          // here is the catch
          Column(children: makeRadios(options)),
        ]);
  }
```

Also, don't use the `Column`, since it has to come aligned. You can use these things as your alternative

- [Row class flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)
- [Wrap class flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

Also, if you want to do this, just check if the `options` List is empty or not, if not then show empty dummy data

Red about [Dart Ternary operator](https://alvinalexander.com/flutter/dart-ternary-operator-syntax-examples/)

```
Container(
  // checking if the options length is not 0, then pass your empty data
  // else call your makeRadios 
  child: options.length != 0 ? makeRadios(options) : TextField()
)
```

Also, if you are worried about listing the `options` from your JSON data, since currently your options is just `String` with commas, like "Yes,No". Then read about [Split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_string_split_method.htm)

With the help of that method, you can store your data into the your options list. I am just giving out a demo for you

```
void main() {
  var options = "Yes,No";
  // if your options from your JSON consists of null 
  // data store an empty array else store an array of your options
  List<String> myOptions = options.split(",") ?? [];
  print(myOptions); // [Yes, No]
}
```